Understanding the relationship between Delta G and Kp, Kx and Kc
**Upon reading the chapter about equilibrium from my physical chemistry book, I was convinced that
ΔG=−RTln(Kp)(1)
and that
Kp=Kx(P∑v)(2)
where Kp
is the equilibrium constant with respect to pressure and Kx
is the equilibrium constant with respect to molar fraction. However, I was not convinced of
ΔG=−RTln(Kx)
As it would have made more sense that given (1) and (2), that:
ΔG=−RTln(Kx(P∑v))
So what am I missing that made me unable to understand how this derivation came to be? Same for Kc, where:
Kp=Kc((RT)∑v)
yet
ΔG=−RTln(Kc)
**

Welcome to ChemSE! Please find guidance for MathJaX / $\LaTeX$ as follows and reformat your post - Basics // MathJaX and mhchem formatting for equations and chemical formulae // Guidelines on which should be upright / italics
